# How can I get my Android 13 GSI Bluetooth Connectivity to work?

Tags: android, bluetooth, driver, fingerprint, android-13

I installed the Android 13 GSI onto my OnePlus 7. My phone can see and pair to Bluetooth devices, but it cannot connect to them. When I try to connect the paired device, nothing happens. I also face other issues such as (mentioned) no audio input or output on phone calls, and no under-screen fingerprint sensor functionality. Is there any way that I can get Bluetooth and/or these hardware components to work with stock Android? Drivers? Apps?